# Matching ${123...456} and extracting 2 numbers in Java?

Tags: java, regex

What is the simplest succinct way to expect 2 integers from a String when i know the format will always be `${INT1...INT2}` e.g. "Hello `${123...456}` would extract `123,456`?

Comment: Are the dots are placeholders for arbitrary characters? Are your ints always three digits?

Comment: first split it with 3 dots, got a String Array, say t. num1 = t[0].split("${")[1], num2 = t[1].substring(0, t[1].length() - 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with a `Pattern` with groups and back-references.

Here's an example:

```
String input = "Hello ${123...456}, bye ${789...101112}";
//                           | escaped "$"
//                           |  | escaped "{"
//                           |  |  | first group (any number of digits)
//                           |  |  |    | 3 escaped dots
//                           |  |  |    |       | second group (same as 1st)
//                           |  |  |    |       |    | escaped "}"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\d+)\\.{3}(\\d+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
// iterating over matcher's find for multiple matches
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found...");
    System.out.println("\t" + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("\t" + m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Found...
    123
    456
Found...
    789
    101112
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String string = "${123...456}";
final String firstPart = string.substring(string.indexOf("${") + "${".length(), string.indexOf("..."));
final String secondPart = string.substring(string.indexOf("...") + "...".length(), string.indexOf("}"));
final Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(firstPart.concat(secondPart));
```